# How to check token for already defined policy?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, signalr

This is how I handle authorization with policies for controller:

At "Startup.cs", in "ConfigureServices" method I add following code:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("can_work", policy => policy
      .RequireClaim("my_app", "user", "admin")
    );
});
```

And then all it takes is to decorate given controller or specific method with attribute:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "can_work")]
```

As the effect only users with matching policy are granted the usage of controller/method.

Now, I have situation when I cannot rely on just attributes -- I have user token at hand and I have to decide whether to grant access or not. I could manually replicate the above policies rules, but it means I would repeat myself in two places. So I would like to somehow retrieve those policies I set already and check for which the token matches. How to do it?

---

Maybe I rephrase -- I know I can manually iterate over token claims:

```
foreach (var claim in token.Claims)
    // manually check the value and type, and basically repeat policy again
```

this would be (a) repeating (b) prone to errors when something change. Instead I would like to have single call

```
policy_service.GetPoliciesForToken(token);
```

which will hit the authorization service I defined with policies (see top of the question). And currently I don't know how to write such line.

**Background** I describe what I need this is for, because maybe there is even simpler way -- SignalR broadcasting. When client calls SignalR method I could use attribute as well, but when the service initiates flow, say every 1 second it sends to all its clients a tick, then I would like to know to which client I can send it. So my idea would be to check user tokens when connecting to SignalR hub, retrieve matching policies (this part I don't know how to do it **reusing** already set policy options), and then when broadcasting anything simply filter out the clients based on cached info.

*For the time being for security concerns it is sufficient for me.*

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. The user token should contain all the user claims (after parsed). It the token is just an input attached to a request. So right at the init stage, it should be verified and parsed for the corresponding claims. The authorization policy you defined then should work against those claims automatically.

Comment: @KingKing, at one hand I have token, it contains the claims. I know how to manually retrieve them, and manually check if for example claims contain "admin". The problem I have is this is **repeating** myself, I already wrote the code handling claims. So I would like to instead of manually checking token call `policy_service.GetPoliciesForToken(token)`. This way I could be 100% sure, that if I change the meaning of given claim it will affect all code. As for your last sentence it works automatically (thanks to attributes) for incoming call, not for broadcasting (outgoing).

Comment: If your web supports cookie authentication (supporting signed-in session), the logic to parse for user claims ***is not repeated*** at all. It's the logic when you sign in the user. But if your system supports both cookie & token authentication (which does not sign in the user), then the claims extracting logic may be repeated. But we can refactor that logic into one common service or class for reusing in other places (signing-in, verifying token ...). We can always avoid repeated code because we has control over the logic (not some kind of built-in logic).

Comment: @KingKing, I suspect the repeating can be avoided, but for now I don't know how to reuse the code. I defined policies when calling `services.AddAuthorization`, this works for sure, so I have working definition, now I would like to refer to it and check against token. And this I don't know how to do.

Comment: the built-in authorization policy does not work directly with token but with claims. So looks like you don't have an easy way to reuse that built-in logic (there may be some way if we look into its source code). BTW you mentioned about the `outgoing request`, this is not clear to me. So what's the target? a third party endpoint or your api endpoint? That seem solvable by propagating the identity instead.

Comment: @KingKing, getting claims from token is as easy as calling `token.Claims`, so how would you call built-in authorization policy to retrieve all policies matching given claims? Outgoing = transfer started by service and goint to clients (users). Consider for example timer service which sends tick every 1 second to all connected clients.

Comment: actually it works on the current `User` (which holds claims), of course the built-in logic is in its source code, it's processed in a designed pipeline. As far as I know there is no authorization api accepts `claims`. There is only one accepting `ClaimsPrincipal` (which is `User`) called `IAuthorizationService`. You can give it a try to see if it works. Note that it accepts a `resource` (for resource-based authorization).

Comment: actually you want to authorize it again with the available token to ***filter*** the users, not to authorize to any external endpoint. I believe that the built-in logic is put in some implementations of `IAuthorizationHandler` (e.g: to handle the requirement `ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement`). So theoretically to authorize it manually (and reuse the built-in logic), you need to get such instances of `IAuthorizationHandler`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following King King tips, to some degree now I have one definition and shared check.

I changed how policies are built. I build them manually and keep their instances also for my purposes (see later):

```
AuthorizationPolicy work_policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireClaim("my_app", "user", "admin")
            .Build();
```

then having policy instances I call `services.AddAuthorization(options...` which works as before for controllers.

As for SignalR hub I request in constructor `IAuthorizationService`, and when user connects thanks to attribute `Authorize` I have `this.Context.User` provided on one hand, and I have my policies instances, thus I can make such call:

```
AuthorizationResult auth_result = await authService.AuthorizeAsync(this.Context.User, work_policy);
```

to check if given user matches or not given policy.